# How to configure jackson object-mapper in spring-servlet.xml for @RequestBody conversion?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson-databind

I want to display a server-side ajax Data-Table. To do this, I need to get the data from my Controller.

My Request would be something like this (from form):

```
var form = { "order":"12r34e56e", "state":"open"}
```

And my Controller should parse it to an Object which I can send to a WebService and receive all open packages from the order in a list. The received list also has to be convert to JSON format to display it in the table.

My header looks like

> http://localhost:8080/myWebapp/ordernr/getTableData?{%22orderNummer%22:%2212r34e56e%22}&_=1563526347735

I already tried successfully with RequestParam. But my Form includes some more Filterparams like date1, date2, Adress and so on. So there are too much variables. 
And I tried in vain to annotate

```
consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

I didn´t change my Form-Object-Class "PreparedStatement" because onSubmit my Form without ajax works fine.

in my **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**in my Controller**

```
@Controller
public class Ordernr extends OrderService {
...
@RequestMapping(value="/ordernr/getTableData", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getTable(@RequestBody PreparedStatement ps) {
    OrderService().getOrders(ps);
    return result;
}
...
```

**my ajax call**

```
"ajax": {
    type: "GET",
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTableData",
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType:"json",
    data: function(data) {
                var form = { "order":"12r34e56e", "state":"open"} 
                return JSON.stringify(form);
          }
    }
```

My JSON is valid. I tested it in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
but i get

> "Error parsing HTTP request header. Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986"

I think I need to configure the ObjectMapper from Jackson in my spring-servlet.xml but I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question. 
First I had to add relaxedQueryChars='{}' in my Tomcat server.xml Connector

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" relaxedQueryChars='{}' />
```

Next thing: Spring does not allow RequestBody for RequestMethod.GET. So I changed to POST and it works. Because of:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I did not have to make any configurations to jackson objectmapper.

Comment: for your self trial .. kudos !!